# How to throw custom exception from transactional Spring service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have this spring service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ConsorcioServiceImpl implements ConsorcioService {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private ConsorcioRepository consorcioRepository;

    @Override
    public void saveBank(Consorcio consorcio) throws BusinessException {

        try {
            consorcioRepository.save(consorcio);
        }
        catch(DataIntegrityViolationException divex) {
            if(divex.getMessage().contains("uq_codigo")) {
                throw new DuplicatedCodeException(divex);
            }
            else {
                throw new BusinessException(dives); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
    }


}
```

That service uses this Spring Data repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ConsorcioRepository extendsCrudRepository<Consorcio, Integer> {


}
```

I'm calling the service from a spring controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/bank")
public class BancaController {

    @Autowired
    private ConsorcioService consorcioService;

    @RequestMapping(value="create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView crearBanca(@Valid BancaViewModel bancaViewModel, BindingResult bindingResult,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView;

        MessageViewModel result;
        try {

            consorcioService.saveBank(bancaViewModel.buildBanca());
            result = new MessageViewModel(MessageType.SUCESS);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageViewModel", result);
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/banca/crear");
            return modelAndView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = new MessageViewModel(MessageType.ERROR);
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("crear-bancas");
            modelAndView.addObject("messageViewModel", result);
            return modelAndView;
        }
}
```

But the exception I get in the controller is: `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`
instead of the `DuplicatedCodeException` I throw in the service. I need to identify the type of exception so I can give a custom friendly user message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also your DuplicatedCodeException , BusinessException should be runtime exception , or add for method saveBank :

> @Transactinal(rolbackFor={BusinessException.class,DuplicatedCodeException.,class })

in other case spring will not rollback transaction.

from Spring documentation:

> While the EJB default behavior is for the EJB container to
>   automatically roll back the transaction on a system exception (usually
>   a runtime exception), EJB CMT does not roll back the transaction
>   automatically on an application exception (that is, a checked
>   exception other than java.rmi.RemoteException). While the Spring
>   default behavior for declarative transaction management follows EJB
>   convention (roll back is automatic only on unchecked exceptions), it
>   is often useful to customize this.

Comment: I inherited from `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception` and the behavior was as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `catch (TransactionSystemException tse)` before `catch (Exception e)` branch and then extract your exception with `getOriginalException()`.

```
try {
    consorcioService.saveBank(bancaViewModel.buildBanca());
    result = new MessageViewModel(MessageType.SUCESS);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageViewModel", result);
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:/banca/crear");
    return modelAndView;
} catch (TransactionSystemException tse) {
    final Throwable ex = tse.getOriginalException();
    if (ex instanceof DuplicatedCodeException) {
        // DuplicatedCodeException
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = new MessageViewModel(MessageType.ERROR);
    modelAndView = new ModelAndView("crear-bancas");
    modelAndView.addObject("messageViewModel", result);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because your exception is wrapped in `RollbackException` as `Throwable` cause. In it's turn `RollbackException` is also a cause of `TransactionSystemException`.

You can build global exception handler to catch and customize all exceptions as you wish:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT) 
    @ExceptionHandler(TransactionSystemException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleDupilatedCode(HttpServletRequest req, TransactionSystemException ex) {
        // Build you exception body here
        Throwable e = ex.getOriginalException();
        if(e instanceof DuplicatedCodeException)
          // throw
        // Or build custom exception as you want
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName("error");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

`@ControllerAdvice` is available since Spring 3.2

Also you can use `@ExceptionHandler` at the `@Controller` level, or create this handling in abstract-controller if you have one as a super class of all your controllers.

```
public class FooController {

    //...
    @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class })
    public void handleException() {
        //
    }
}
```

There are some other approaches, for full reference please follow the:

[Spring IO: Exception handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

[Baeldung: Exception handling with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

Comment: After a couple of hours fighting this (and at least 3 other ways of trying to get this to work using @ControllerAdvice), the simple change of making this extend TransactionSystemException rather than Exception did it. Thank you!