# Is it possible to get an InvalidFormatException not as a HttpMessageNotReadableException in Spring when processing JSON?

Tags: json, spring

I have a simple RestController:

```
@RestController
public class MailboxController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mailbox/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void createMailbox(@PathVariable @NotNull String mailboxID, @Validated @RequestBody Mailbox mailbox){
    //do something with Mailbox here        
    }
}
```

The Mailbox class looks as follows:

```
@Validated
public class Mailbox{

    @JsonProperty("email")
    @EmailValidator //some validation of EMail String
    public String email;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public Type type; //Type is an enum
}
```

If I post a valid JSON-String where the value of `type` is not listed in the enumeration then I get a 400 (Bad Request) error. Internally a `HttpMessageNotReadableException` with a `InvalidFormatException` gets thrown. If I post a JSON-String where the email doesn't get accepted by the EmailValidator I get a 400 (Bad Request) error as well (from a  `MethodArgumentNotValidException`). In both cases I would expect a 422 since the JSON is well formatted but the content is semantically wrong.

Either way I try to handle both cases similary and wonder if there is a way to redirect the `InvalidFormatException` in a way that I get `MethodArgumentNotValidException` when the given `type` is not part of the `Type` enumeration.

Currently I have a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` with one method that catchest the `HttpMessageNotReadableException` and builds the `ResponseEntity` depending on the causing exception and a method that handles the `MethodArgumentNotValidException`. I would prefer it if the `InvalidFormatException` could be handled in the method where I handle the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` as well.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575617/how-to-throw-custom-exception-from-transactional-spring-service/44576339#44576339

Comment: @J-Alex this answer seems like a cleaner solution. So I will check it out at home some time. But since it will also need some time to check it out and understand it properly, I will continue using our current solution i.e. we got a class that extends `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and will handle exceptions there seperatly as needed, partly overriding methods from the base class and partly using the `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.